# Unresolved reference: enableAssertions

Tags: automated-testing, java, learning, assert, test-execuation

working [assertions](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/programming-with-assertions-in-java-part-1) example using [standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) Java SE with no imports:

```
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ javac App.java
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ java -ea App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at App.main(App.java:12)
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ java App
Dec 21, 2018 1:56:23 AM App main
INFO: false
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ cat App.java 
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class App {



    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isFoo = false;
        assert isFoo;
        LOG.info(String.valueOf(isFoo));
    }
}

thufir@dur:~/jshell$
```

But, trying to get that to run from Gradle:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAssertions$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAssertions$ gradle clean

> Configure project :
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloAssertions/build.gradle.kts:42:9: Unresolved reference: enableAssertions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/HelloAssertions/build.gradle.kts' line: 42

* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 42:         enableAssertions = true
                   ^ Unresolved reference: enableAssertions

1 error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/HelloAssertions$
```

build file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    java

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building an application
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre")

    // Use TestNG framework, also requires calling test.useTestNG() below
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClassName = "HelloAssertions.App"
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}

run{
        enableAssertions = true
}
```

How else should I [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48396274/262852) assertions?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify the flag for the JUnit platform. Reference on the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178018

Comment: But *how* would I enable the flag through *kotlin* gradle DSL?  Java SE assertions:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html